# Adding logs to wso2 to track logs implemented in custom java code

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Below I have a code snippet for a custom API manager mediator, I'm suppose to modify this code for our use. I'm having trouble though getting the logs out of the code when I'm running it in our wso2 environment. What would be the process to be able to the outputs of these logs. This is going to be a jar file I add to the repository/components/lib/ directory of the APIM. The jar file name is com.domain.wso2.apim.extensions. I need to be able to see whats being passed and what parts of the code are being hit for testing

```
public class IdentifiersLookup extends AbstractMediator implements ManagedLifecycle {

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(IdentifiersLookup.class);
private String propertyPrefix = "";
private String netIdPropertyToUse = "";
private DataSource ds = null;
private String DsName = null;

public void init(SynapseEnvironment synapseEnvironment) {
if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info("Initializing IdentifiersLookup Mediator");
}
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    log.debug("IdentifiersLookup: looking up datasource" + DsName);
try {
    this.ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(DsName);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    log.debug("IdentifiersLookup: acquired datasource");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line to log4j.properties file resides wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf/ folder and restart the server.

> log4j.logger.com.domain.wso2.apim.extensions=INFO

Comment: Thanks for your help